# Nginx set not working in nested location directive

Tags: nginx

I have the following directive:

```
location ~ "^/v1" {
  set $api_version 'v1';

  location ~ "^/v1/someEndpoint$" {
    # the rest goes here
  }
}
```

However, `$api_version` is not set when I hit `/v1/someEndpoint` - I have to `set $api_version 'v1';` within that inner/nested location directive.

Why is that? Why can't I `set` at the top-level directive for common variables?

Answer (score 1):

Many nginx directives do not nest (`proxy_pass`), while others nest only if the directive is not used inside the nested block (`set_header`).  My best guess is that the `set` directive falls into one of these two categories.  Discovering which directives fall into which category is a matter of trial-and-error and a lot of searching (and sometimes code-reading).

Comment: Actually `set` directive in third category — `rewrite` module directives :)